# Ввод строки с клавиатуры

Tags: строки, c++

Задача: ввод строки с клавиатуры строки (состоящей из нескольких слов) и запись её в массив для дальнейшего использования.

```
char nazv_sh[100];
cout << "Введите название нового шаблона :" << endl;
gets(nazv_sh);
```

При запуске после того, как высвечивается предложение о вводе, вводишь одну букву, и программа вылетает. Не пойму, в чём дело, и как тут правильно поступить.

Comment: @Дарьялла а у меня работает. Но вообще iostream и gets смешивать нехорошо.

Comment: а как можно ещё сделать, чтобы добиться выполнения поставленной задачи?

Comment: Должно работать. А iostream c stdio по умолчанию синхронизируются.

Answer (score 4):

У меня все работает. Вообще, как писали выше, не надо смешивать `stdio` и `iostream`. Если пишете на плюсах, то делайте что-то вида:

```
char nazv_sh[100];  
cout << "Введите название нового шаблона :" << endl;  
cin >> nazv_sh;
```

Comment: @gothmog, `cin >>` прочтет очередное "слово", а не строку.

Чтение строки (в нормальных крестах) в `string`

     string str;
     getline(cin, str);

А в `char[]`, конечно, stdio:

     fgets(nazv_sh, sizeof(nazv_sh), stdin);
     nazv_sh[strlen[nazv_sh] - 1] = 0;

Comment: @avp данные грабли -- в faq (или как он там пишется)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string nazv_sh;
    cout << "Введите название нового шаблона :" << endl;
    getline(cin, nazv_sh);
    return 0;
}
```